# Swagger для Asp.Net. Api возвращает анонимный тип. Можно ли в swaggerUi показывать пример ответа?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

Методы моих Api контроллеров принимают тип object в качестве параметра (json) и возвращают object (json) в ответ, который формируется в хранимых процедурах.

```
    public Object TestSwagger(Object requestParams)
    {
        return myService.CallStoredProcedure(requestParams);
    }
```

На фронте хотят чтобы через Swagger было видно пример входящих параметров и возвращаемого объекта, то есть пример джейсона. На официальном сайте Сваггера есть пример как это сделать через Swagger Editor, однако я использую для сваггера Swashbuckle и не совсем понимаю как это сделать в моём случае. Был бы благодарен за любые советы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во первых не использовать `object`. А использовать свои "нормальные" типы объектов.

Если Вы все таки потом приводите `object` к какому то типу и никак не хотите менять тип возвращаемого значения и тип аргумента то используйте атрибуты :

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesErrorResponseType(typeof(void))]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BankDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
```

Для аргументов нет никаких атрибутов, то есть Вы никаким образом не сможете сказать о своих соглашениях - так как огромная вариативного того какой у Вас аргумент и какой способ его предоставления `[FromBody]` или `[FromQuery]`. Так что лучше переписать контроллер так :

```
public ResponseObject TestSwagger(RequestObject requestParams)
{
    return myService.CallStoredProcedure(requestParams);
}
```

И Swagger сможет сгенерировать для Вас нормальные соглашения!

[Подробнее об атрибутах](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

[Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я понимаю что без строго-типизированной модели трудно формировать примеры параметров и ответов через сваггер, однако требования со стороны менеджмента таковы что переписывать код "времени нет", но примеры реквестов и респонсов сделать надо. Понимаю что это решение не корректное, однако может есть какое-то, пускай костыльное, но решение.